# Does a Grignard reagent react with enones to give the 1,2- or 1,4- product?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, grignard-reagent, regioselectivity

[image: Reaction of phenylmagnesium bromide with cyclohex-2-en-1-one]

Cyclohexenone, an α,β-unsaturated ketone, is electrophilic at both the carbonyl carbon, as well as the β-carbon. So, it can either undergo 1,2-addition to give the allylic alcohol **1**, or 1,4-addition to give the ketone **2**.

Where does the Grignard reagent add to?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The correct answer is the 1,2-addition product (i.e. the allylic alcohol **1**). In general, Grignard reagents and organolithium reagents add directly to the carbonyl carbon, while organocuprates (organocopper reagents) add to the beta-position of an unsaturated ketone.

This exact transformation was reported by Akai and coworkers recently ([*Org. Lett.* **2010,** *12,* 4900](https://doi.org/10.1021/ol102053a)) and they obtained compound **1** in 95% yield (the supplementary information [(PDF)](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/suppl/10.1021/ol102053a/suppl_file/ol102053a_si_001.pdf) is free).

Answer (score 14):

The Grignard reaction, although very well examined, there are still arguments about the mechanism and the overall process.  The reagent is usually best described via the [Schlenk equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlenk_equilibrium), but that is not only dependent on $\ce{X}$, but also on the solvent:

$$\ce{2RMgX <=> R2Mg + MgX2}$$

There also have been some dimeric structures reported, i.e. the symmetrical, the asymmetrical, and the alkyl bridging dimer. According to Milton Orchin<sup>[1]</sup> (and references therein) the latter is responsible for the formation of the above equilibrium.

[image: Grignard dimers]

There are many mechanism possible, two of them following a non-radical pathway are depicted below. In both cases, the 1,2-addition leads to the major product. The six-membered transition state (top route) has been proposed many times and employs the alkyl bridging dimer.<sup>[2]</sup>

The bottom route considers only the monomeric Grignard reagent. Whichever pathway is taken, the result is the same: 1,2-addition, resulting in a tertiary alcohol, with the C=C double bond retained.

[image: Mechanism]

---

**Notes and References**

It has been correctly pointed out by ron that Grignard agents cannot coexist with acid, as my previous draft suggested. Even water poses a big threat to the stability, as pointed out by yasir. I was a little confused about this, because adding a $\ce{Cu(I)}$ co-catalyst will result in the 1,4-product,<sup>[3]</sup> and I assumed the same would happen with an acid.

1. [M. Orchin, *J. Chem. Educ.*, **1989**, *66* (7), 586.](https://doi.org/10.1021/ed066p586)
2. See for example: [E. C. Ashby. *A detailed description of the mechanism of reaction of Grignard reagents with ketones*. International Conference on Organometallic Chemistry, ICOMC, Organometallic Chemistry, IX, University of Dijon, France, 1979-09-03–1979-09-07.](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac198052030545) Also available for free at [iupac.org](https://www.iupac.org/publications/pac/1980/pdf/5203x0545.pdf).
3. [M. S. Kharasch, and P. O. Tawney, *J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, **1941**, *63* (9), 2308–2316.](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01854a005)

Comment: But this doesn't reason out why 1,4 wont happen. Is it that Grignard always gives 1,2?

Comment: @user223679 According to all the papers I read so far, the 1,2-addition is always favoured. The most likely second pathway is reductive elimination, but that cannot happen with $\ce{PhMgX}$. Radical pathways are favoured in presence of co-catalysts and might result in a 1,4-adduct. Also often observed is a pinacol type product.

Comment: Here is a [link](https://books.google.com/books?id=82CaxfY-uNkC&pg=PA381&dq=rakita,+grignard+conjugate+addition+to+carbonyl&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vJ1cVcjGA8exyAS7qID4Bw&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=rakita%2C%20grignard%20conjugate%20addition%20to%20aldehyde&f=false)  to some interesting information on the subject, see p. 285 and p. 382

Comment: @ron Interestingly enough on p.382 they convert the ketone into the methyl group with the acid in the second step.