# Reactions of Grignard Reagent: 1,2 vs 1,4 addition

Tags: organic-chemistry, grignard-reagent

So I was reading through Grignard reagent and I came across [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/31660/5026) answer by jerepierre, which mentions:

> In general, Grignard reagents and organolithium reagents add directly to the carbonyl carbon, while organocuprates (organocopper reagents) add to the beta-position of an unsaturated ketone.

Now, I want to know, what is the meaning of '**in general**'? Can anyone please provide me some cases where the general rules are not followed.

Also, I came to know that:

[image]

give 1,4 addition with $\ce{PhMgBr}$ to give:

[image]

(that reference is difficult to provide at the moment).

Can someone please explain why this happened?

Comment: Can you work on getting that reference?  I am getting feedback on my answer asking for it, but you made the claim.  Thanks!

Comment: @OscarLanzi Sorry... but at my current level its impossible to procure citations. All claims made here are according to what my instructor taught me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a 1,4 addition.  It is a 1,2 addition across a carbon-carbon double bond.  This mode of reaction is unusual for Grignard reagents, but here a highly stabilized "double benzylic" anion is formed and the competitive reaction of adding to the carbonyl group is sterically hindered.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: I'm going by what the asker posted.  The 1,2 attack forming the carbanion is the only way to get the claimed product.  I think the asker needs a reference for the claim.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Can you explain formation of 'carbanion'?