# Why is direct addition not preferred in this reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, reaction-control

> [image]

According to HSAB, direct addition is more preferrable in this reaction with the hard carbonyl carbon electrophile and the hard grignard reagent. But answer given in my book is that with 1,4- addition. I would like to know why 1,4-addition is done here? Thermodynamic control? But I don't think the reaction is reversible.

Comment: strong nucleophile gives 1,2 addition only

Comment: It seems that the answer in your book may be wrong. Refer here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31618/does-a-grignard-reagent-react-with-enones-to-give-the-1-2-or-1-4-product?rq=1